# Как набирать практический опыт в разработке на asp.net

Tags: c#, .net

Изучаю c#/asp.net core около полугода, перечитал кучу литературы и проделал кучу примеров. Никак не решусь сделать что-то большое в соло, посоветуйте плиз что сделать и как получать практический опыт?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.